# Javascript HTML web maps

Tags: geojson, html, html5

I am very new to javascript and html. I am trying to display a web map, which works, but my issue is trying to figure out how to add a local geojson file to my html code. Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.36.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <script src="/javascript_codes/operatingZone.js"></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.36.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW1ja2VldmVyOTIiLCJhIjoiY2oxemQwOWl5MDF6ODJxazIxdXh4ajJpayJ9.7HndcHlQ1y3y8XAVmP7WKg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    zoom: 12,
    center: [-97.749291, 30.285157]

$.getJSON('operatingArea.js').addTo(map)
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is where the issue is trying to display the Geojson:

```
$.getJSON('operatingArea.js').addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON()` is JQuery. Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) documentation on how to use it. You need to provide an URL to get a `.json` file and a function on what to do with that file on the success or error of its return.

Comment: Even if the json file is stored on my computer in a folder?

Comment: Yes. The file will need to live on the server your code is running on though. Here is a related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28931478/5759427). If this is not what you want then I'd look into a file upload form.

Comment: Glad to be of some help. If this solved your issue please "accept" this as your answer.